# QListWidget removeItemWidget gives bluish background effect after Deleting?

Tags: qt

QListWidget removeItemWidget gives bluish background effect after Deleting ?
I dont want to use takeItem property.
I am using removeItemWidget , the customwidget deletes also from QListWiget but leaves a blueish selection affect at that area.

```
 ui->UsersList->removeItemWidget(ui->UsersList->currentItem());
```

Any help/ideas is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
ui->UsersList->selectionModel()->clear();
```

before removing the item widget.

This obviously clears the whole selection. If this doesn't suit your needs you would have to remove the selection only from the item you want to delete.

Comment: This Works   ui->UsersList->selectionModel()->clearSelection(); but after that the widget that got deleted show the spcae behind it , the next item does not take the position of the deleted item

Comment: If you don't need the item afterwards you can do `delete ui->UsersList->currentItem()` (without calling removeItemWidget additionally) and it should be removed from the list as well. But I don't know why you don't just use takeItem()